# AWS api gateway error when content length is greater than 1024

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, content-length

When i try to request aws api gateway, browser fails when the response content-length is greater than 1024. 
ie the request gets success on small data and not with big data.

**Response header in case of Error:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Authorization, Credentials, UserId
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Aug 2017 15:47:53 GMT
ETag:W/"2e66-gh/gyPzUq3KxiQAslibZJg"
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Surrogate-Control:no-store
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express
```

**Response Show in console in case of error**

```
https://********/v1/centers net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED  (chrome)

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data (Firefox)
```

**Response Header in case of success**

```
access-control-allow-headers →Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Authorization, Credentials, UserId
access-control-allow-methods →GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin →*
cache-control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
content-length →838
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Fri, 25 Aug 2017 04:44:52 GMT
etag →W/"346-I99yuNQRDTf/UvarDA7kdw"
expires →0
pragma →no-cache
status →200
surrogate-control →no-store
vary →Accept-Encoding
via →1.1 1ed35878396a5c073c88fd1b51c4f47a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id →WEICithhcr5_GNYeXUUa35lvUIsicZCOnyPLdfbLm54hlS6sO3rIcw==
x-amzn-remapped-connection →keep-alive
x-amzn-remapped-content-length →838
x-amzn-remapped-date →Fri, 25 Aug 2017 04:44:51 GMT
x-amzn-requestid →224537d0-8950-11e7-ab72-bfe4c43d695f
x-cache →Miss from cloudfront
x-powered-by →Express
```

Swagger json definition for Api gateway

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "2017-08-23T06:36:43Z",
    "title": "ProxyResourceForFsApi"
  },
  "host": "**********",
  "basePath": "/v1",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/{proxy+}": {
      "options": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "proxy",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Empty": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Empty Schema"
    }
  }
}
```

Same request succeed when the data coming from the server is less and fails when it is greater.

Comment: It's get or post method

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: According to the API Gateway [limits][1], it can return a Payload size of maximum 10 MB which is way larger than your test dataset. On the other hand it can only support maximum integration timeout of 30 seconds. Can you check whether 30 second limit hits?

Comment: @MohanShanmugam In every method, the system fails when the data coming from the server is greater than 1024.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Updated the question

Comment: @Ashan No it responds with in 1496ms.

Comment: What is your configuration for AWS lambda. Increase the time out and memory of lambda and try. You are getting part of response that's why it can't able to decode the json.

Comment: @MohanShanmugam I am not using lambda function. Used HTTP proxy configuration for setting up api gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first hint is here: `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

This failed response has this:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

The "decoding" error is talking about a failure decoding the encoding.

But that is something of a distraction.  The real issue is here:

```
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

API Gateway apparently does not support chunked transfer-encoding on responses.  This is also sometimes referred to as a "streaming response."

Why is 1024 the error threshold?  Your back-end appears to be using 1024 as a minimum size before it begins gzipping responses.  This might not be a problem, except that when your back-end decides it needs to gzip the response, it also switches to a streaming response.

The successful response isn't being streamed:

```
x-amzn-remapped-content-length →838
```

Streaming responses with chunked transfer-encoding don't specify a content-length.

The solution will involve convincing your back-end not to stream its responses, which probably means convincing it not to gzip responses.

This could be done on the back-end, but there may be an easy workaround:

In the Integration Request, add an HTTP header `Accept-Encoding` with a value of `'identity'`.  The `'` single quotes are needed because the header value is an expression, and we need to tell API Gateway that it's a literal string.

Comment: Thank you. I updated Accept-Encoding but still failing. Now endpoint request timeout error is showing.